# SQL query to display items from two tables only if it occurs more than once

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, Evidence and Suspect.

In my Evidence table, I am only concerned with the Hash column and the SuspectID column for now.
The Suspect Table columns of interest are SuspectID, SuspectFirstName,SuspectLastName, and Suspect.SuspectState.

I want to make a connection between Evidence.Hash and Suspect.SuspectID. I want to be able to display all of the suspects that are associated with the specific evidence file. ie:

"File [hash of file] is connected to Suspect1, Suspect2, and Suspect3"
"File [hash of file2] is connected to Suspect1, and Suspect2"

I want to make these connections only if the evidence file is connected to more than 1 suspect.

Here's what I have so far. Nothing has worked completely:

This prints out the file hashes that have more than 1 suspect ID connected to them. I need to also include the suspect name and state.

```
SELECT Evidence.Hash 
FROM Evidence 
GROUP BY Evidence.Hash 
HAVING COUNT(Evidence.SuspectID) > 2
```

This returns all of the hashes with all of the suspects sorted by hash. This is OK but I'd rather not have them just listed out.

```
SELECT Evidence.Hash, Evidence.SuspectID, SuspectFirstName, Suspect.SuspectLastName
FROM Evidence
INNER JOIN Suspect 
ON Evidence.SuspectID=Suspect.SuspectID 
ORDER BY Evidence.Hash
```

I'd like to combine the 2 queries. I tried the following but now nothing prints to the screen.

```
SELECT Evidence.Hash, Evidence.SuspectID, SuspectFirstName, Suspect.SuspectLastName
AS FileHash  
FROM Evidence
INNER JOIN Suspect
ON Suspect.SuspectID = Evidence.SuspectID
GROUP BY Evidence.Hash,Evidence.SuspectID, SuspectFirstName, Suspect.SuspectLastName
HAVING Count(Evidence.SuspectID )> 1
```

If anyone can help me out and show me how to get the hashes that are connected to more than 1 suspectID, I would be grateful.

Comment: You will probably get no results because of your having statement. Do you get any results back without it?

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, should be working.

```
SELECT 
    Evidence.Hash AS FileHash, 
    Evidence.SuspectID, 
    Suspect.SuspectFirstName, 
    Suspect.SuspectLastName   
FROM 
    Evidence
    INNER JOIN Suspect ON Suspect.SuspectID = Evidence.SuspectID
GROUP BY 
    Evidence.SuspectID
HAVING 
    COUNT(Evidence.SuspectID )> 1
```

UPDATE: If I understood the question correctly, GROUP column should be Suspect.SuspectID

```
GROUP BY 
    Suspect.SuspectID
HAVING 
    COUNT(Suspect.SuspectID )> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to

- get the hashs, for which there are multiple suspects, and then
- join the details.

Try

```
SELECT
  MS.hash FileHash
  , E.SuspectID
  , S.SuspectFirstName
  , S.SuspectLastName
FROM (
  SELECT
    E.hash
  FROM Evidence E
  JOIN Suspect S
    ON E.SuspectID = S.id
  GROUP BY E.hash
  HAVING COUNT(E.SuspectID) > 1) MS
JOIN Evidence E
  ON MS.hash = E.hash
JOIN Suspect S
  ON E.SuspectID = S.id
;
```

There might be alternatives - but can't test them right now.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `window function` to find the `Evidence.Hash` which is present more than once in `Evidence` table

```
;with cte as
(
SELECT row_number() over (partition by Hash order by SuspectID) Rn, *
FROM Evidence 
)
select * from cte where rn>1
```

Now join the result with `Suspect` table

```
;with cte as
(
SELECT row_number() over (partition by Hash order by SuspectID) Rn, *
FROM Evidence 
)
select Evidence.Hash, Evidence.SuspectID, SuspectFirstName, Suspect.SuspectLastName
  from cte Evidence 
  join Suspect
    on Evidence.SuspectID=Suspect.SuspectID
where rn>1
```